# вопрос про безопасность

Tags: python, файлы

всем здравствуйте, я начал делать телеграм бота, и столкнулся с проблемой: дав пользователям возможность программировать, я жертвую безопасностью. тоесть человек может выполнить `open(file, mode)`, и мне сломать весь код. так вот, как перехватить запрос на открытие файла и на другие события? типо вот так:

```
try:
    open(file, mode) #человек пытается открыть файл, и его перебрасывает на исключение.
except:
    print('файлы запрещены')
```

Comment: вы можете проверять что вам дают, как-то так, думаю. `if func in (open, os.mkdir, ...): raise Exception('Not allowed'`, где `func`- функция, которую пользователь ввел на выполнение

Comment: спасибо тебе огромное, ты спас меня

Comment: пользователь может еще много чего наделать. надо изолировать пользователя в виртуальной среде. хотя бы chroot сделать в отдельную папку или использовать под каждого пользователя отдельный docker контейнер. И думаю специально для таких вещей есть еще какие нибудь еще более подходящие технологии

Comment: а то вы open запретите, а пользователь какой нибудь библиотекой, да хоть csv воспользуется и через нее файлы открывать будет

Comment: а я написал просто запрет на функции и классы. это очень удобно